# Shooting Bullets with mouse, Math.atan2

Tags: java, math

So i code a 2D Shooter were you  use the mouse to shoot:

```
timeSinceLastShot+=timeSinceLastFrame;
        double bullet_angle = Math.atan2(MyMouseListener.getClickPosY()-posY, MyMouseListener.getClickPosX()-posX);
        float bullet_startX = posX+(skin.getWidth()/2)-(Bullet.getImg().getWidth()/2);
        float bullet_startY = posY+(skin.getHeight()/2)-(Bullet.getImg().getHeight()/2);
        double bullet_speedX = Math.cos(bullet_angle * Math.PI/180)*500;
        double bullet_speedY = Math.sin(bullet_angle * Math.PI/180)*500;

        if(timeSinceLastShot>(1f/shotsPerSec) && MyMouseListener.isButtonClicked(MouseEvent.BUTTON1)){
            bullets.add(new Bullet(bullet_startX, bullet_startY, bullet_speedX, bullet_speedY));
            timeSinceLastShot = 0;
        }
```

All Bullets go to the right, but i want them to go exactly in the direction of the mouse.

Comment: I’m *guessing* Java. Can you please tag your language if that wasn’t it? C++?

Comment: @minitech can't be C++. Class seperator is `.` here. That's C# or Java.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Can’t be C# — `Math` methods would be capitalized. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to convert the bullet_angle to radians, but it is already in radians. Essentially, the bullet_speed is being calculated at angle=zero, which is straight right. Remove "* Math.PI/180" from your cos() and sin() calculations.

```
timeSinceLastShot+=timeSinceLastFrame;

double bullet_angle = Math.atan2(MyMouseListener.getClickPosY()-posY, MyMouseListener.getClickPosX()-posX);
float bullet_startX = posX+(skin.getWidth()/2)-(Bullet.getImg().getWidth()/2);
float bullet_startY = posY+(skin.getHeight()/2)-(Bullet.getImg().getHeight()/2);
double bullet_speedX = Math.cos(bullet_angle)*500;
double bullet_speedY = Math.sin(bullet_angle)*500;

if(timeSinceLastShot>(1f/shotsPerSec) && MyMouseListener.isButtonClicked(MouseEvent.BUTTON1)){
    bullets.add(new Bullet(bullet_startX, bullet_startY, bullet_speedX, bullet_speedY));
    timeSinceLastShot = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I really appreciate your support!